# Display Multiple JsonObject on Listview

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I have a Json from the server as below:

```
{    
"data": {
            "komik_popular": {
                "title": "Yei! Komik Awas Nyamuk Jahat jadi literasi terpopuler minggu ini lho!"
            },
            "buku_baru": {
                "title": "Ada buku baru nih, Katalog Prasekolah"
            }
        },
    }
```

I want to display the json on the listview, but I try `Debug.Writeline("judul: " + highlight.Title)` first

Code:

```
Highlight highlight = new Highlight();
                    string title = "";
                    string urlPath = link;
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
 var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SCH-API-KEY", "SCH_KEnaBiDeplebt")
                    };
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
 string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    try
                    {
                        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                        JsonObject jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetObject();
                        JsonObject bukuBObject = jsonData.ContainsKey("buku_baru") && jsonData["buku_baru"] != null ? jsonData["buku_baru"].GetObject() : JsonObject.Parse("");
                        try 
                        { 
                            title = bukuBObject["title"].GetString();
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }

                        JsonObject komikPObject = jsonData.ContainsKey("komik_popular") && jsonData["komik_popular"] != null ? jsonData["komik_popular"].GetObject() : JsonObject.Parse("");
                        try
                        {
                            title = komikPObject["title"].GetString();
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }
                        highlight.Title = title;
                        Debug.WriteLine("judul: " + highlight.Title);
}
```

Highlight.cs:

```
class Highlight
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm having a problem, when I try to debug only the title on "komik_popular" is displayed, I want all the data in "komik_popular" and "buku_baru" to be displayed. How to handle it?

Comment: Can you mention what's your expected json output ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Highlight > HighlightList = new List<Highlight>();

                   string urlPath = link;
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
 var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SCH-API-KEY", "SCH_KEnaBiDeplebt")
                    };
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
 string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    try
                    {
                        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                        JsonObject jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetObject();

                        JsonObject komikPObject = jsonData.ContainsKey("komik_popular") && jsonData["komik_popular"] != null ? jsonData["komik_popular"].GetObject() : JsonObject.Parse("");
                        try
                        {
                            Highlight highlight = new Highlight();

                           string title = "";

                            title = komikPObject["title"].GetString();

                            HighlightList.Add(highlight);
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }
                        JsonObject bukuBObject = jsonData.ContainsKey("buku_baru") && jsonData["buku_baru"] != null ? jsonData["buku_baru"].GetObject() : JsonObject.Parse("");
                        try 
                        { 
                          Highlight highlight = new Highlight();

                           string title = "";

                            title = bukuBObject["title"].GetString();

                          HighlightList.Add(highlight);
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }


                  }
                  catch
                   {
                    }
                       foreach( Highlight items in HighlightList)
                      {

                        Debug.WriteLine("judul: " + items .Title);
                      }
}
```

Comment: try this above updated code. in which i am creating new highlight object and add into list.

Answer (score 0):

for converting json data to list, first you have to create respective class model as per given data format after that you can convert or deserialize it in your list format , in cae of your json data you can follow below example :-

```
public class Titel
{
    public string title { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public Titel komik_popular { get; set; }
    public Titel buku_baru { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "{'data':{'komik_popular':{'title':'Yei! Komik Awas Nyamuk Jahat jadi literasi terpopuler minggu ini lho!'},'buku_baru':{'title':'Ada buku baru nih, Katalog Prasekolah'}}}";
        List<RootObject> dataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(s);
    }
}
```